# why I can not put something by using hbase-client

Tags: java, hbase, hbase-client

**===>Java<====**

environment

```
apache-zookeeper-3.6.3
hadoop-2.10.1
hbase-2.3.5
```

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
                <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
                <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

when I put something into table.

```
    public static void put() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("==> put value");

        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hap10,hap11,hap12");

        Connection con = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);

        Table tbl = con.getTable(TableName.valueOf("newTbl1"));

        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("1001"));
        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("info"), Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("newName"));

        tbl. put(put);

        tbl.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("==>");
    }
```

I have Exception below:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56683', transport: 'socket'
==> put value
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,114 - 0    WARN  [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader:62  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,413 - 299  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.7-f0fdd52973d373ffd9c86b81d99842dc2c7f660e, built on 02/10/2020 11:30 GMT
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,413 - 299  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:host.name=192.168.31.59
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,413 - 299  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_121
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,413 - 299  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,413 - 299  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:java.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/panpengfei/Documents/development/server/java/hbase-demo/demo-1/target/classes:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-client/2.3.5/hbase-client-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/thirdparty/hbase-shaded-protobuf/3.3.0/hbase-shaded-protobuf-3.3.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-common/2.3.5/hbase-common-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-logging/2.3.5/hbase-logging-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/thirdparty/hbase-shaded-gson/3.3.0/hbase-shaded-gson-3.3.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-hadoop-compat/2.3.5/hbase-hadoop-compat-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-metrics-api/2.3.5/hbase-metrics-api-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat/2.3.5/hbase-hadoop2-compat-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-metrics/2.3.5/hbase-metrics-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-protocol-shaded/2.3.5/hbase-protocol-shaded-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-protocol/2.3.5/hbase-protocol-2.3.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.13/commons-codec-1.13.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/thirdparty/hbase-shaded-miscellaneous/3.3.0/hbase-shaded-miscellaneous-3.3.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/thirdparty/hbase-shaded-netty/3.3.0/hbase-shaded-netty-3.3.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.5.7/zookeeper-3.5.7.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper-jute/3.5.7/zookeeper-jute-3.5.7.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.45.Final/netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.45.Final/netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.45.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.45.Final/netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.45.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.45.Final/netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.45.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.45.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core4/4.2.0-incubating/htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jcodings/jcodings/1.0.18/jcodings-1.0.18.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/jruby/joni/joni/2.1.11/joni-2.1.11.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.2.6/metrics-core-3.2.6.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-crypto/1.0.0/commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.10.0/hadoop-auth-2.10.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/4.41.1/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0-1/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-kerberos-codec/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-i18n/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-asn1-api/1.0.0-M20/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-util/1.0.0-M20/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.7.1/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.10.0/hadoop-common-2.10.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.10.0/hadoop-annotations-2.10.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-sslengine/6.1.26/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.7/avro-1.7.7.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.5/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.54/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.7.1/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.7.1/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.19/commons-compress-1.19.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.3/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar:/Users/panpengfei/.m2/repository/org/apache/yetus/audience-annotations/0.5.0/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Users/panpengfei/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/panpengfei/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/yq/bsk22g9n52z0hdklt98w4f140000gn/T/
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:os.name=Mac OS X
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:os.arch=x86_64
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:os.version=10.15.7
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,414 - 300  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:user.name=panpengfei
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,415 - 301  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:user.home=/Users/panpengfei
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,415 - 301  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:user.dir=/Users/panpengfei/Documents/development/server/java/hbase-demo
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,416 - 302  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:os.memory.free=98MB
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,416 - 302  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:os.memory.max=1820MB
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,416 - 302  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.Environment:109  - Client environment:os.memory.total=123MB
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,422 - 308  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper:868  - Initiating client connection, connectString=hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$12/1278636355@19635bda
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,429 - 315  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util:79  - Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,442 - 328  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket:237  - jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,450 - 336  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn:1653  - zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,471 - 357  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553-SendThread(hap11:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread:1112  - Opening socket connection to server hap11/10.211.55.12:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,501 - 387  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553-SendThread(hap11:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread:959  - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.211.55.2:56686, server: hap11/10.211.55.12:2181
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:47,626 - 512  INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-hap10:2181,hap11:2181,hap12:2181@0x72bc6553-SendThread(hap11:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread:1394  - Session establishment complete on server hap11/10.211.55.12:2181, sessionid = 0x3000bbb4b8a0011, negotiated timeout = 40000
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:52,675 - 5561 INFO  [hconnection-0x19e4fcac-metaLookup-shared--pool4-t1] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl:134  - Call exception, tries=6, retries=16, started=4742 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: hbase:meta,,1 is not online on hap12,16020,1625315267897
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:3358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.newRegionScanner(RSRpcServices.java:3148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:3490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:44858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:318)
, details=row 'newTbl1,1001,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hap11,16020,1625315268939, seqNum=-1, see https://s.apache.org/timeout
[frame] 2021-07-03 21:59:56,695 - 9581 INFO  [hconnection-0x19e4fcac-metaLookup-shared--pool4-t1] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl:134  - Call exception, tries=7, retries=16, started=8762 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: hbase:meta,,1 is not online on hap12,16020,1625315267897
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:3358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.newRegionScanner(RSRpcServices.java:3148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:3490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:44858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:318)
, details=row 'newTbl1,1001,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hap11,16020,1625315268939, seqNum=-1, see https://s.apache.org/timeout
```

I have same exception ,while I check table `tableExists`

```
    public static void tableIsExist() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("==> table is exist");
        TableName tn = TableName.valueOf("newTbl");
        System.out.println(admin.tableExists(tn));
        System.out.println("====>");
    }
```

but I successfully created table or namespace,and successfully drop table or namespace

**=====>shell<=====**

I do same thing in shell, all is OK

```
hbase(main):018:0> put "newTbl2","1001","info:name","mary"
Took 0.3352 seconds
hbase(main):019:0> scan "newTbl2"
ROW                                                  COLUMN+CELL
 1001                                                column=info:name, timestamp=2021-07-03T22:09:10.953, value=mary
1 row(s)
Took 0.2424 seconds
hbase(main):020:0>
```

hbase-root-master-hap10.log

```
2021-07-03 22:07:49,898 INFO  [master:store-Store-Compactor] region.MasterRegionUtils: Moved hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/MasterData/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/1695e7c4d03f49ad86c330bde3073c95 to hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/1695e7c4d03f49ad86c330bde3073c95$-masterlocalhfile-$
2021-07-03 22:07:49,900 INFO  [master:store-Store-Compactor] region.MasterRegionUtils: Moved hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/MasterData/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/1f36af0ec4584b04a987afdf3d43c9b2 to hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/1f36af0ec4584b04a987afdf3d43c9b2$-masterlocalhfile-$
2021-07-03 22:07:49,902 INFO  [master:store-Store-Compactor] region.MasterRegionUtils: Moved hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/MasterData/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/a98e5d89cf29497dab122c96802502a0 to hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/a98e5d89cf29497dab122c96802502a0$-masterlocalhfile-$
2021-07-03 22:07:49,907 INFO  [master:store-Store-Compactor] region.MasterRegionUtils: Moved hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/MasterData/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/f9719dea834446ed8c562888e1d5be97 to hdfs://hap10:8020/hbase/archive/data/master/store/1595e783b53d99cd5eef43b6debb2682/proc/f9719dea834446ed8c562888e1d5be97$-masterlocalhfile-$
2021-07-03 22:07:56,123 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.2] hbase.ChoreService: Chore ScheduledChore name=HbckChore-, period=3600000, unit=MILLISECONDS is enabled.
2021-07-03 22:07:56,124 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.2] hbase.ScheduledChore: Chore: HbckChore- missed its start time
2021-07-03 22:07:56,135 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.2] balancer.BaseLoadBalancer: Start Generate Balance plan for cluster.
2021-07-03 22:07:56,137 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.2] balancer.StochasticLoadBalancer: start StochasticLoadBalancer.balancer, initCost=35.0, functionCost=RegionCountSkewCostFunction : (500.0, 0.0); PrimaryRegionCountSkewCostFunction : (500.0, 0.0); ServerLocalityCostFunction : (25.0, 0.0); RackLocalityCostFunction : (15.0, 0.0); TableSkewCostFunction : (35.0, 1.0); RegionReplicaHostCostFunction : (100000.0, 0.0); RegionReplicaRackCostFunction : (10000.0, 0.0); ReadRequestCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0); WriteRequestCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0); MemStoreSizeCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0); StoreFileCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0);  computedMaxSteps: 9600
2021-07-03 22:07:56,191 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.2] balancer.StochasticLoadBalancer: Could not find a better load balance plan.  Tried 9600 different configurations in PT0.055S, and did not find anything with a computed cost less than 35.0
2021-07-03 22:07:56,210 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.2] master.HMaster: Normalizer ran successfully in PT0.019S. Submitted 0 plans, affecting 0 tables.
2021-07-03 22:07:56,279 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.9] master.HbckChore: Loaded 4 regions from in-memory state of AssignmentManager
2021-07-03 22:07:56,317 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.9] master.HbckChore: Loaded 4 regions from 3 regionservers' reports and found 0 orphan regions
2021-07-03 22:07:56,369 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.9] master.HbckChore: Loaded 4 tables 4 regions from filesyetem and found 0 orphan regions
2021-07-03 22:12:55,179 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.9] balancer.BaseLoadBalancer: Start Generate Balance plan for cluster.
2021-07-03 22:12:55,188 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.9] balancer.StochasticLoadBalancer: start StochasticLoadBalancer.balancer, initCost=35.0, functionCost=RegionCountSkewCostFunction : (500.0, 0.0); PrimaryRegionCountSkewCostFunction : (500.0, 0.0); ServerLocalityCostFunction : (25.0, 0.0); RackLocalityCostFunction : (15.0, 0.0); TableSkewCostFunction : (35.0, 1.0); RegionReplicaHostCostFunction : (100000.0, 0.0); RegionReplicaRackCostFunction : (10000.0, 0.0); ReadRequestCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0); WriteRequestCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0); MemStoreSizeCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0); StoreFileCostFunction : (5.0, 0.0);  computedMaxSteps: 9600
2021-07-03 22:12:55,243 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.9] balancer.StochasticLoadBalancer: Could not find a better load balance plan.  Tried 9600 different configurations in PT0.059S, and did not find anything with a computed cost less than 35.0
2021-07-03 22:12:55,294 INFO  [master/hap10:16000.Chore.7] master.HMaster: Normalizer ran successfully in PT0.122S. Submitted 0 plans, affecting 0 tables.
```

Comment: check your region server is up and running. maybe master is only up

Comment: Please do **not** write in all-bold (edited); bold is for **emphasis** only.